# Trying to make my C# WEB API 2 return an Object, but getting Error 500

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to send a login and a password and if it find in the DataBase it shold return the account details. But i am getting this error on my console:

> ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", url: "http://localhost:56624/api/Usuarios"

And here is my API code: 
`

```
public Usuarios Post([FromBody]LoginRequest login)
        {
        var usuario = new Usuarios();
        var con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["comidas"].ConnectionString);
        var com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE loginUsuario = @loginUsuario AND senhaUsuario = @senhaUsuario", con);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loginUsuario", login.loginUsuario);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@senhaUsuario", login.senhaUsuario);

        con.Open();

        var rdr = com.ExecuteReader();

        if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
            usuario.idUsuario = (int)rdr["idUsuario"];
            usuario.loginUsuario = (string)rdr["loginUsuario"];
            usuario.senhaUsuario = (string)rdr["senhaUsuario"];
            usuario.nomeUsuario = (string)rdr["nomeUsuario"];
            usuario.emailUsuario = (string)rdr["emailUsuario"];
            usuario.telefoneUsuario = (string)rdr["telefoneUsuario"];

            return usuario;
        }

        con.Close();

        return null;

    }`
```

If you guys spot any mistake pleasse tell me, i am new to C#.

Here is the request code in javascript:

```
getUser() {

    let head = new HttpHeaders();
    head.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let body = {
        loginUsuario: '*login*',
        senhaUsuario: '*password*'
    }

    return this.http.post(this.url + 'Usuarios', body, { headers: head }).subscribe(data => {

        this.user = data;

        console.log(data);

    });

}
```

and the classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MeinNahrungAPI.Models
{
    public class Usuarios
    {
        public int idUsuario;
        public string loginUsuario;
        public string senhaUsuario;
        public string tipoUsuario;
        public string nomeUsuario;
        public string emailUsuario;
        public string telefoneUsuario;
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MeinNahrungAPI.Models
{
    public class LoginRequest
    {
        public string loginUsuario;
        public string senhaUsuario;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCsaZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koOWq.png)

Comment: problem could be in the http request code too. you may need to provide that too. Further, have you put the attribute [HttpPost] on action method, and whether LoginRequest class property matches with post data in http request?

Comment: If there's an error happening server-side then the first thing you need to do is get the actual error.  When you step through in a debugger, what happens in this method?  Can you wrap the entire contents of the method in a try/catch and capture any exceptions?  Configure the application to return detailed error messages to the browser?

Comment: You haven't included the actual error or the stacktrace we can only speculate without this information.

Comment: I will re-post down here the Request and the classes, but i think the problem is in the C# api code, and i will try it too David give me some minutes lol

Comment: I edited whit the new informations guys, and i sent an image whit what i belive is the error, i am really NOOB whit C# or even visual studio mechanics

Comment: @Kirchesch: *"what i belive is the error"* - Why do you believe that?  What is the indication?  Don't guess, nor ask us to guess.  Debug.  This is a great opportunity to practice stepping through the code in the debugger.  When the code is paused on a debugging breakpoint, hover over variables to see what they contain.  Are they what you expect?  Step through each line as it executes to see its result.  Is it what you expect?  Does execution reach the end of the method as expected?  Does the method return what you expected?

Comment: @David Nice nice, well, it tells me "System.InvalidOperationException" Invalid try to read when there's not data" then it dont allow me to breakpoint anything furter

Comment: @Kirchesch: The *exact* error message is "Invalid try to read when there's not data"?  And this happens *exactly* on the line which invokes `.ExecuteReader()`?

Comment: I have uploaded a new image, unfortunately my Visual Studio is in Portuguese, this error i told you is my poor translation

Comment: Aparently its what is writen: Invalid read attempt when no data exists

Comment: @Kirchesch: Ah, that makes more sense now.  So the reader *has* rows, but you need to call `.Read()` in order to get those rows.  Take a look at the examples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=netframework-4.7.2  I'll add more details as an answer below.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i have been stuck on this part of API's for some hours, the worst part is that i made it work on vb.Net like a week ago, but i dont have acess to that project rn

Comment: Damn it worked just fine, i just added rdr.Read() before filling the Object, take care bro, if there is a way to give you a point its my first problem on this site, just let me know

Comment: @Kirchesch: Answer posted below :)  You are free to vote and/or accept the answer as you see fit.  These actions do indeed award me points, but more importantly they indicate to the community that you found the content helpful.  So if future visitors have a similar problem they may be helped as well.  (This is why the exact error message is often important, so other users searching for it can find this question.)  Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result of the comment thread on the question...

You're getting an exception here:

```
usuario.idUsuario = (int)rdr["idUsuario"];
```

I'm not familiar with the specific translation of the exception from your Portuguese settings, but essentially what it means is that you're attempting to read data when none is available.  Which is *slightly* misleading, since there *is* data returned from the query (which is why `rdr.HasRows` resolves to `true`).  *But* you haven't called `rdr.Read()` to access the first record in the results.  Even if there's only one record, technically it's still a collection of records which happens to have only one entry.  And a `DataReader` needs to be told to progress through that collection.

Take a look at [some examples here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader).  Specifically at how they structure reading the results:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    //...
}
```

In this case calling `.Read()` returns a `bool` indicating whether or not there is a next record to read, but it *also* is quietly advancing the `DataReader` internally to access that next record.

You *can* use this same loop structure and expect it to only loop one time since there should be only one returned record.  (It wouldn't hurt to add in some error checking to handle unexpected possibilities if more than one record is returned.)  Or you could even just call `.Read()` once:

```
if (rdr.HasRows)
{
    rdr.Read();
    // the rest of your code
}
```

---

Another thing to note, which is unrelated to the problem but is **important** regardless.  First off, as a beginner, the fact that you're using query parameters instead of directly concatenating string values is a *very good thing*.  However, there's another security problem in your code that you should be made aware of.  You are storing user passwords in plain text.  This is a *very bad thing*.  You don't want to be able to ever see or know your users' passwords.

There are existing authentication tools in the .NET Framework which can do much of the work for you.  But even when creating your own, you should always *hash* the passwords.  (Not *encrypt*, *hash*.  It's a very important distinction.)  And with good hashing methods (*not* MD5).  That way nobody can ever recover the original password.  Not an attacker, not even you as the system owner.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the last advice, i know about encrypt, i just builded this api rn to test if it would work, so i can work on it whit my own C# api, you have been very helpfull take care!